# HTML tags and directives are not recognized by Intellij IDEA

Tags: angular, typescript, intellij-idea

I can't navigate anymore between my HTML and TS files in Intellij IDEA; tags, directives and autocompletion in HTML are disabled. I've got some warnings:

[image]

How could I restore the original config for all files to develop my Angular app?

Comment: Do you have angularJS plugin installed and enabled? Can you navigate to @angular modules from your .ts files?

Comment: @jonsharpe thx i have uninstalled the plugin, it works now :)

Answer (score 2):

Head over to Settings | Plugins.

Deselect AngularJS plugin -> Apply -> OK -> Restart IDE.

After indexing is done head over to Plugins again

Select AngularJS Plugin -> Apply -> OK Restart IDE.

It should be fine after indexing is done.